# How can I set up Hyperledger fabric network with two Organisations(one anchor and one endorsement) and one channel without using hyperledger composer

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, blockchain, hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

I want to setup Hyperledger fabrics environment for approval process using Endorsement policy so I have some doubts/questions in fabric setup:

1. Help me How can I set up  Hyperledger fabric network with two Organisations(one anchor and one endorsement) and one channel without using hyperledger composer?
2. How to write the endorsement policy?
3. How to add the organisation for the existing channel, is there any credential required to adding the organisation?
4. How can i change ordered node from solo to Kafka?
5. Is certification same for all the peers within the organisation?

Comment: Have you looked at https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.4/build_network.html ?

Comment: Have you looked through the Fabric documentation?  This is all covered there.  I ask as perhaps we need to make things more clear if you've already read through the docs.

Answer (score 0):

1. You should read through the tutorial noted my comment above
2. I think you might be confusing endorsement with a signature-based approval process.  They are not the same thing.  Endorsement policy determines how many peers from different orgs must agree on the output of a chaincode execution.  If you use the peer cli to instantiate your chaincode, you'd use policies of the form `"OR('Org1.member', 'Org2.member')"` (require endorsement from either Org1 or Org2) or `"AND('Org1.member', 'Org2.member')"` (require endorsement from both Org1 and Org2.
3. You will need to [execute config update transaction](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.4/channel_update_tutorial.html) on the channel and add the org definition (which will include it's [MSP definition](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.4/msp.html))
4. You cannot migrate from Solo to Kafka.  In any case, you should actually make sure you are on the latest 1.4.x and [set up Raft-based ordering](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.4/raft_configuration.html).

Comment: then, how to develop signature-based approval process?

Comment: perhaps you can escape your use case in a bit more detail?

Comment: You might also want to check out some of the upcoming private data enhancements in Fabric v2.0 - https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/private-data/private-data.html#private-data-sharing-patterns

Comment: At maximum how many organisation can be created in one channel, as per document, given only three organisation.

Comment: there is really no practical limit for number of orgs in a channel

Comment: At maximum how many peer can setup in the organisation and how to give the role to peers link anchor peer and endorsement peer and leader peer